# pattern match any into a list

Tags: json, scala, design-patterns

I get the following as a result from using the scala json parse.

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON._
val j: String = """["this",["a","b",["c","d"]]]"""
val parse_test=parseFull(j)
```

now from this I get a result of Option[Any]

I can use `get` to obtain the results (in this case I am not concerned about invalid json format, so this should be safe, right?)

```
parse_test.get
res26: Any = List(this, List(a, b, List(c, d)))
```

Now, how should I go about going from this `Any` to the `List` that I had expected? I assume I should use pattern matching, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify what is missing for you? What do you mean by "the `List` that I had expected"? What _was_ the list you expected? Literally.

Comment: basically, I mean, I would have though that the result would already by a list, as in I could do `parse_test.get.head` etc. The json string that i have I want to manipulate as a List of the form List(a,List(a,b,List(c,d))). Does this make sense?

Comment: You say you get `List(this, List(a, b, List(c, d)))` but you want `List(a, List(a, b, List(c, d)))` ? No, you don't make sense. What happened to the `"this"` string?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, I want the list that seems to return `List(this, List(a, b, List(c, d)))` but what I want to know, is why doesn't it behave like a list to begin with? why can't I just do parse_test.get.head or other such operations? So, my end question is: what do I have to do to that parse_test so that I can use it like every other list I have ever used before.

Comment: If you want to be able to treat an Option[List[Any]] like a List[Any] just do parse_test.getOrElse(Nil) and operate on it.  If you're wanting to extract the 2nd value as the list of strings I think my solution should work nicely for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is a fold with a pattern match and a cast:

```
test_result.fold[List[String]](Nil){
  case _ :: list :: _ => list.asInstanceOf[List[String]]
  case _ => Nil
}
```

Assuming you're trying to throw out of the first element and that the 2nd element is the list you wanted.

Edit:

Be aware that if the 2nd element isn't a list this cast would cause an exception.  It's *really* horrible dealing with a List[Any] and trying to decode what's in there...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
scala> val Some(xs @ List(_*)) = parse_test
xs: List[Any] = List(this, List(a, b, List(c, d)))
```

Comment: This will result in a match error if the value of parse_test is None, but after reading the poster's question maybe he doesn't care.  I would think something like deserializtion should have that kind of safety, but *shrug*.